# Ordering some XML nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, mapping, xslt-1.0, biztalk

I am using XSLT 1.0

I have an input message i am trying to transform. This input messages is composed of 4 types of nodes A, B, Order, Article. Like this one:

```
A
B
Order0
Article100
Article102
A
B
Order1
Article101
A
B
A
B
A
B
etc
```

My goal is to put the A and B nodes at the beginning of the message, so I have:

```
A
B
A
B
A
B
A
B
A
B
Order0
Article100
Article102
Order1
Article101
```

So here is am example:

**Input**

```
<Messages>
    <Message>
        <A>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </A>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <B>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </B>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <Order>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </Order>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <Article>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </Article>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <Article>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </Article>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <A>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </A>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <B>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </B>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <Order>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </Order>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <Article>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </Article>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <A>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </A>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <B>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </B>
    </Message>
</Messages>
```

**Output**

```
<Messages>
    <Message>
        <A>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </A>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <B>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </B>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <A>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </A>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <B>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </B>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <A>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </A>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <B>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </B>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <Order>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </Order>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <Article>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </Article>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <Article>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </Article>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <Order>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </Order>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <Article>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </Article>
    </Message>
</Messages>
```

I am unfortunately limited by xslt 1.0 as I am working on an old version of Biztalk.
I thought about maybe using an order by, but only targeting those A and B nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really only have those elements to sort you could simply name them directly, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Messages">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Message[A or B]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Message[not(A) and not(B)]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVrvcy1/1

Comment: Working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this by sorting, you could do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Messages">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Message">
            <xsl:sort select="number(A or B)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```